# reusing the connection string for stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, dapper

I have code using EF with a connection string as in web.config (spaces and line breaks for clarity) :

```
connectionString=
metadata=res://*/Models.XXXDataContext.csdl|
         res://*/Models.XXXDataContext.ssdl|
         res://*/Models.XXXDataContext.msl;

provider=System.Data.SqlClient;

provider connection string="data source=xxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;
                           initial catalog=db1;
                           user id=dba;
                           password=its-a-secret(bazinga!);
                           MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
                           App=EntityFramework"
```

I want to use the same connection string to execute a stored procedure to perform a `merge insert/update` to another table.

Can I user the connection string as is to create `sqlConnection(cnns-tring)`?

What is the purpose of the `metadata=res: ...` entry here? also `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` and `App=EntityFramework`? Would they have any impact here?

Comment: If looking to use ADO you can get a connection or command from the context and execute as needed

Comment: Do you want to reuse the connectionstring or the connection object?

Comment: reuse connectionstring and I was hoping to use dapper

Answer (score 0):

The **metadata** property specifically points to the location of the .SSDL (Storage Model,) .CSDL (Conceptual Model,) and .MSL (Mapping Model) files. These three files essentially are the Entity Data Model. The "res://" URI-style qualifier indicates that the files are embedded as resources in the compiled EDM assembly.

**MultipleActiveResultSets** - Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) is a feature that works with SQL Server to allow the execution of multiple batches on a single connection. When MARS is enabled for use with SQL Server, each command object used adds a session to the connection.

**App=EntityFramework**: It's just the synonym of the Application Name.
All connectionstring  keywords are explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx